# Spark Scala: difference in App execution vs line by line in REPL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, closures

I have a simple word count program packed as `object`:

```
object MyApp {

  val path = "file:///home/sergey/spark/spark-2.2.0/README.md"

  val readMe = sc.textFile(path)

  val stop = List("to","the","a")

  val res = (readMe
    .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
    .filter(_.length > 0)
    .map(_.toLowerCase)
    .filter(!stop.contains(_))
    .map((_, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .sortBy(-_._2)
    )

  println(res.take(3).mkString)
}
```

When I try to execute it I get:

```
scala> MyApp
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:386)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:386)
  ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MyApp$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: MyApp$, value: MyApp$@7bd44868)
    - field (class: MyApp$$anonfun$5, name: $outer, type: class MyApp$)
    - object (class MyApp$$anonfun$5, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
```

(the culprit being `.filter(!stop.contains(_))` line.

However, when I execute the same code line by line it runs well and produces expected results.

I would really appreciate answers to 2 questions:

1. What is so different between line-by-line execution and singleton execution, so that one runs whereas the other fails?
2. What could be other solutions than packing `!stop.contains(_)` closure together with `stop` list into another object?

Comment: Did you try putting all of the code inside a main? Or maybe adding `extends App` to your object definition?

Comment: @philantrovert I am executing this code `as-is`in `spark-shell`

Answer (score 0):

**Generally Speaking**. Your program is a little **strange**.

**Let me help to illustrate the detail. Hope it will help you!**

You said you got correct answer if the program was executed line by line. From your description context, **i guess this happened in spark-shell, right?**

One important to note is that, if you open spark-shell in spark package, your are in **a REPL environment**, there will be **a pre-constructed spark context object for you already, making your own SparkContext will not work**.

For example,

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master local[4]
```

Now you want to get **an spark application**, represented by an program text. Such as your file `MyApp.scala`, then the parallel operation on **RDD**, here for **readMe, a RDD[String]**, the spark will break the job triggered by action take to many tasks and forward there tasks to worker to execute,

**But, now pay your attention to your code!**, in order to have your operation to construct the closure(**those variables and methods which must be visible for the executor to perform its computations on the RDD**), but from your code, all your closure calculation is in you whole object.

**However, in the singleton object MyApp**, SparkContext type, sc, for example, can not and should not be serializable, because it will stand only on driver node to tell spark how to access the cluster, so your submit will fail.

I help to revise this code, you can run it on your machine. But for your purpose, your revised code should be submitted to spark-submit script.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object MyApp {

  private var sc: SparkContext = _

  def init(): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getName)
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  }

  def mission(): Unit = {
    val path = "file:///home/sergey/spark/spark-2.2.0/README.md"

    val readMe = sc.textFile(path)

    val stop = List("to", "the", "a")

    val res = readMe
      .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .filter(_.length > 0)
      .map(_.toLowerCase)
      .filter(!stop.contains(_))
      .map((_, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .sortBy(-_._2)


    println(res.take(3).mkString)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    init()
    mission()
  }
}
```

Please refer to submit usage on [page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), sooner or later you have to use it.

Comment: Thank you for attention to my question! (1) You're right, the code is executed in `spark-shell` (2) I'm not constructing any SparkContext, I am using the one offered by spark shell, so there are no collisions. (3) I still think the problem is not because `SparkContext` is not serializable (I do not understand this part in your answer), but because closure is not properly serialized. The proof: if I put the closure together with `stop` list, or remove it altogether, the code will run. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: One more comment. The question is not about how to submit scala application via `spark-submit` or how to avoid initializing several `SparkContexts` in a row. It's about how to avoid serialization error as you may see from the error log.